# C# Chamar um objeto a partir de uma string

Tags: c#, variáveis, objetos

Eu gostaria de saber se há maneira de chamar um objeto a partir de uma string.

Aqui está um exemplo:

```
public class Butao
{
    public string _Name_;
    public float _Price_;

    public Butao(string name, float price)
    {
        _Name_ = name;
        _Price_ = price;
    }
}

public class DataBase : MonoBehaviour
{    
    string id;

    private void Start()
    {
        var bar1 = new Butao("", 0);
        var bar2 = new Butao("", 0);
        var bar3 = new Butao("", 0);
    }
}
```

Estou a trabalhar em UnityEngine mas não deve diferenciar muito de c# "puro", porque é o que vou realmente usar neste script, e não funções de Unity.
O que eu gostaria de fazer era de através de uma string, a string id, e passá-la diretamente e chamar o objeto com esse nome. Por exemplo:

Se id for igual a "Bar1", eu queria editar as propriedades de Bar1, ou seja,

```
Bar1.Name = "Alterado";
Bar1.Price = 2
```

e por aí em diante.

O problema é que tenho 60 objetos diferentes e não dava jeito ver um a um, daí automatizar o processo.

Comment: _Se id for igual a "Bar1"_. Você não pode criar uma propriedade `Id` e atribuir `"Bar1"` a ela?

Comment: Foi o que eu acabei por fazer, ao juntar o código com o de Thiago Lunardi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voce pode usar [`Collections`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.collections(v=vs.110).aspx) para isso.

```
public class ButaoCollection : List<Butao>
{
    public Butao this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.SingleOrDefault(butao => butao.Name == name);
        }
    }
}
```

E depois usar assim:

```
public class DataBase : MonoBehaviour
{    
    string id;
    public ButaoCollection Butaos { get; set; }

    private void Start()
    {
        Butaos = new ButaoCollection();

        Butaos.Add(new Butao("Bar1", 0));
        Butaos.Add(new Butao("Bar2", 0));
        Butaos.Add(new Butao("Bar3", 0));
    }
}
```

E chamar assim:

```
Butaos["Bar1"].Price = 10;
```

Comment: Onde está especificada a variável Preco e _Preco_?

Comment: Devo juntar o meu código ao seu ou apenas substituir?

Comment: Juntar, sua classe Butao continua sendo a mesma.