# Chamar objeto variável a partir de uma string

Tags: c#

Estou tentando chamar um objeto a partir de uma string, que contem seu *namespace*, classe e nome do objeto, porem, todos estes são variáveis e não tenho um tipo fixo de objeto

Encontrei uma [pergunta parecida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/218381/c-chamar-um-objeto-a-partir-de-uma-string), mas ela não me responde.

Na pergunta acima, o código cria uma lista de um objeto especifico, e necessito chamar objetos de diferentes classes.

Eu tentei o seguinte código, mas os tipos sempre retornam nulos.

```
class tstProcessa
{
    public static void processar(JSON.Arquivo Arq)
    {
        var DE = $"Origem.{Arq.Origem.Empresa}.{Arq.Origem.Sistema}.{Arq.Origem.Tabela}";
        //Origem.x.FINANCEIRO.cadcli;

        var PARA = $"Destino.{Arq.Destino.Empresa}.{Arq.Destino.Sistema}.{Arq.Destino.Tabela}";
        //Destino.y.FINANCEIRO.cadastro_cli;

        Type t1 = Type.GetType("Destino.y.FATURAMENTO.cadastro_cli, AssemblyName");
        Type t2 = Type.GetType(DE);
        Type t3 = Type.GetType("tstProcessa");

        int a1 = 0;
    }
}
```

Existe alguma maneira de Realizar esta chamada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe uma maneira de instanciar objetos a partir de strings, utilizando o `Activator.CreateInstance`.

Ex:

```
var DE = $"Origem.{Arq.Origem.Empresa}.{Arq.Origem.Sistema}+{Arq.Origem.Tabela}"
Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(DE));
```

Sendo o caminho do `GetType` no formato "Namespace"."Classe"+"Objeto".

Dê uma olhada na referência desse método na [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx).